# T-SQL n rows for amount of days between 2 days

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a question which I cannot answer myself. I'm using T-SQL and a basic query:

```
SELECT OpenArt, DayFrom, Dayto 
FROM Locations 
WHERE OpenArt = 'closed' AND S_ID = '123'
```

I want to get every date, where my location is closed. This works so far, as the output is something like:

```
| OpenArt | DayFrom    | DayTo      |
+---------+------------+------------+
| Closed  | 06.12.2019 | 09.12.2019 |
| Closed  | 23.12.2019 | 31.12.2019 |
```

Basically, it shows a range, when a location is closed. However, for an API, I need to send 1 row for each closed day. So for the range 23.12.2019 - 31.12.2019, I'd need 9 single rows like:

```
| OpenArt | DayClosed  |
+---------+------------+
| Closed  | 23.12.2019 | 
| Closed  | 24.12.2019 | 
| Closed  | 25.12.2019 |
```

and so on. The naming of the headers aren't  that important, I can adjust that. I simply don't know how to "dupe" the results, depending on the range between the 2 days. I know there is `datediff()`, but that is all I could come up with. Thanks in advance.

There are no restrictions, there can be a new temp_table, an UDF or anything that works.

Comment: Do you have a calendar table? If not, time to create one; you'll find this trivial once you do.

Comment: The problem is - and bare with me, i don't like it either - this was created a long time ago. Other recipients are in need of that format. The DateFrom + DateTo are stored in smalldatetime(). Would you suggest creating a temp calendar-table?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the format, in my view, but a calendar table makes to trivial, as it'll literally be a simple Join: `JOIN YourCalendarTable CT ON CT.CalendarDate BETWEEN YT.DateFrom and YT.DateTo`

Comment: Alternative to SQL, In C#  you can use Enumerable.Range() to generate the range from 0 to datediff days and produce the result too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use an ad-hoc tally table in concert with a CROSS APPLY,

**Example**

```
Set Dateformat DMY
Declare @YourTable Table ([OpenArt] varchar(50),[DayFrom] date,[DayTo] date)  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('Closed','06.12.2019','09.12.2019')
,('Closed','23.12.2019','31.12.2019')

Select OpenArt
      ,DayClosed = D
 From @YourTable
 Cross Apply (
             Select Top (DateDiff(DAY,[DayFrom],[DayTo])+1) 
                    D=DateAdd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),[DayFrom]) 
              From  master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2
             ) B
```

**Returns**

[image]

**Or Yet another option with known date range**

```
Declare @Date1 date = '2019-01-01'
Declare @Date2 date = '2020-12-31'

Select OpenArt
      ,DayClosed = D
 From @YourTable
 Join ( 
        Select Top (DateDiff(DAY,@Date1,@Date2)+1) 
               D=DateAdd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),@Date1) 
         From  master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2
      ) B on D between [DayFrom] and [DayTo]
```